# Unicode, utf-8, binary, ASCII in Python

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, binary, ascii

1. What are their differences?
2. 

> Python 3.0 uses the concepts of text and (binary) data instead of Unicode strings and 8-bit strings. All text is Unicode; however encoded Unicode is represented as binary data. 
>   
>   What does it mean?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Character Sets explained for Dummies!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049090/character-sets-explained-for-dummies)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to know about unicode and encodings is here - and it's nothing Python-specific : http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

wrt/ the second question: Python3 has two kind of "strings": text strings (which are unicode), and binary strings (aka `bytestrings`), which are not unicode. Encoding a text string (iow unicode) results in a binary string.

Answer (score 2):

### Story:

**[Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/standard/WhatIsUnicode.html)** is a python datatype, for storing *all* characters.

**[UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF_8)** is a variable-width encoding that can represent every character in the Unicode character set. It was designed for backward compatibility with ASCII and to avoid the complications of endianness and byte order marks in UTF-16 and UTF-32.

**[ASCII,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)** The American Standard Code for Information Interchange (ASCII /ˈæski/ ass-kee) is a character-encoding scheme originally based on the English alphabet that encodes 128 specified characters - the numbers 0-9, the letters a-z and A-Z, some basic punctuation symbols, some control codes that originated with Teletype machines, and a blank space - into the 7-bit binary integers.

---

### Summary:

The three are the different forms of the same thing: *String*, aka, *Text*.

---

### Difference:

Ascii is used for plain text like this, but unicode is used for more comprehensive text like:

```
    ∮ E⋅da = Q,  n → ∞, ∑ f(i) = ∏ g(i),      ⎧⎡⎛┌─────┐⎞⎤⎫
                                            ⎪⎢⎜│a²+b³ ⎟⎥⎪
  ∀x∈ℝ: ⌈x⌉ = −⌊−x⌋, α ∧ ¬β = ¬(¬α ∨ β),    ⎪⎢⎜│───── ⎟⎥⎪
                                            ⎪⎢⎜⎷ c₈   ⎟⎥⎪
  ℕ ⊆ ℕ₀ ⊂ ℤ ⊂ ℚ ⊂ ℝ ⊂ ℂ,                   ⎨⎢⎜       ⎟⎥⎬
                                            ⎪⎢⎜ ∞     ⎟⎥⎪
  ⊥ < a ≠ b ≡ c ≤ d ≪ ⊤ ⇒ (⟦A⟧ ⇔ ⟪B⟫),      ⎪⎢⎜ ⎲     ⎟⎥⎪
                                            ⎪⎢⎜ ⎳aⁱ-bⁱ⎟⎥⎪
  2H₂ + O₂ ⇌ 2H₂O, R = 4.7 kΩ, ⌀ 200 mm     ⎩⎣⎝i=1    ⎠⎦⎭
```

---

### References:

- [Unicode
  docs](http://www.unicode.org/standard/WhatIsUnicode.html)
- [UTF-8 (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF_8)
- [ASCII (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)

---

### Suggested further reading:

- http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html
- http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2010/04/i18n-comparing-character-encoding-in-c.html
- http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html
- http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/examples/UTF-8-demo.txt

---

Comment: Unicode is used for "plain text", too. Just take a look at any non-English website.

Comment: no i didn't mean "only for comprehensive text" and not for plain text. i meant, _also_ for comprehensive text..